# Where can I find good reference/tutorial on writing Apache modules (in C)?

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2-module

I've looked all over and can't really find much of anything. I need three basic things:

1. Good API reference
2. Some sort of a tutorial
3. Good architectural overview

I have the module source code and am going through it - but I really don't have much of any context for most of the things its doing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nick Kew's book http://www.apachetutor.org/#book about apache module development is the most helpful resource I was able to find.

Comment: Yes, Nick Kew's book is indispensable!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is the list of links about apache module development that I found useful:

[Apache Tutor](http://www.apachetutor.org/)

[Apache Modules Development and Debugging](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~jcw5q/talks/)

[libapr(apache portable runtime) programming tutorial](http://dev.ariel-networks.com/apr/apr-tutorial/html/apr-tutorial.html)

[The Apache Modules Book: Application Development with Apache](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132409674)

[Mailing list archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/)

[Apache at WebÞing](http://apache.webthing.com/)

[Writing portable C code with APR](http://people.apache.org/~rooneg/talks/portable-c-with-apr/apr.html)

[Apache Modeling Project](http://www.fmc-modeling.org/projects/apache)

You can also download the apache source code and experiment with mod_example.

Comment: Thanks! I did get that book, and have been experementing with some of the modules - but I will check out the links you provided. Thank you!

Comment: I just wanted to clarify - that Nick Kew's book was by FAR the most helpful resource.